# Properly match every line of JS multiline comment

Tags: javascript, regex

// I have this **string**:

```
var a = "/**  \n" + 
        "  * foo bar  \n" + 
        "  * baz bob  \n" + 
        "  *  \n" + 
        "  * Yes, it is a string containing a docstring  \n" + 
        "  */  ";
```

// Having some experience in regex, I wrote a JavaScript regex expression:

```
var r = /\/\*\*\s*(.*\s*)*\*\//g;
```

// That regex successfully captures, as expected,

// but only the last line of the docstring in its second capture:

```
var match = r.exec(a.toString());  console.log(match);

// ["/**
//  * foo bar
//  * baz bob
//  * Yes, it is a string containing a docstring
//  */", 
//  "* Yes, it is a string containing a docstring"
// ]
```

// In order to capture all lines in this "string" similar to match[1], what am I still missing?

// This question is its own fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **dotall** flag, which in most languages is the `s` modifier, **does not exist** in Javascript.

You can work around this by using `\s` and its negation `\S` together in a character class. `[\S\s]`

```
var r = /\/\*\*\s*([\S\s]*)\*\//g;
```